# Make Kafka ignore object's deserialiser and use Kafka deserialiazer

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a scenario where I have custom implemented deseralization to my class `Item extends JsonDeserializer<User>` which deserializes my object in one fashion.

While Kafka uses `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer` which is being overridden by this my new implementation.

How can I make my Kafka stop from using the custom implementation ?

Custom Implemented code

```
public class ItemDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Item> { 

public ItemDeserializer() { 
    this(null); 
} 

public ItemDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
    super(vc); 
}

@Override
public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    int id = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("id")).numberValue();
    String itemName = node.get("itemName").asText();
    int userId = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("createdBy")).numberValue();

    return new Item(id, itemName, new User(userId, null));
}}
```

And while using custom deserialiser, I call it like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Item.class, new ItemDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

Item readValue = mapper.readValue(json, Item.class);
```

Item class is annotated with

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ItemDeserializer.class)
public class Item {
   public int id;
   public String itemName;
   public User owner;
}
```

Kafka Configurations

```
consumer:
   deserializer:
      key.delegate.class: com.apache.kafka.common.serialization.stringDeserializer
      value.delegate.class: com.apache.kafka.common.serialization.JsonDeserializer
json:
   trusted:
      packages: com.package.to.item
```

Tried Searching for 3 days. This is my last resort on how to solve this problem

Comment: What exactly do you mean overrides? What are you seeing vs what you expect? You've made and configured a new ObjectMapper. This shouldn't interfere with the Deserializer's own ObjectMapper. You'll have to show your Kafka client properties

Comment: These are my Kafka Configurations.

Comment: `stringDeserializer` is also incorrect... Have you not copied these exactly from your code? And, so you've defined delegates, but where are your actual deserializer settings defined? And you've still not answered my questions about what you want vs what you get

Comment: What's happening: Kafka stringDeserializer is not being called. Instead my ItemDeserializer.class is being called.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your own ObjectMapper. If you want to configure Spring-Kafka's ObjectMapper instance, then [see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#tip-json)

> make my Kafka stop from using the custom implementation

If you want to use the String Deserializer rather than JSON, then you don't need [delegates](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#delegating-serialization). Simply set the deserializer directly

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: com.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer:  ...
```

Beyond this, unclear why you'd actually want strings that you'd need to deserialize yourself rather than consuming actual Item classes